# How to change a user's name in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm not asking how to change the user's login, which is doable with [sp_change_users_login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259633%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), but really the user's name (which comes under the Name column of the list of users in Enterprise Manager).

Is there a stored procedure to do it? Some other command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2000, I think you'll have to drop and re-create the user, unless you want to reply on crazy hacks like this one:

- [Rename User Login](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30178/)

I don't really recommend that, both because updating system catalogs is dangerous, and also because it uses undocumented, unsupported, and buggy `sp_MSForEachDB` (see [why I urge you to stay away from that one](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)).

In versions newer than SQL Server 2000, it is as simple as:

```
ALTER USER foo WITH NAME = bar;
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll just drop 'em. It really doesn't seem supported in 2000.